# The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I have implemented a linq expression to return a resultset and getting the following error

{"The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."}

```
public IEnumerable<TBI.JV.Business.Objects.Asset> GetAssetsBasicBySedols(string[] sedols)
    {
        var priceDate = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(-8);
        var typeList = new string[]
            {
                "UNIT TRUST",
                "OEIC",
                "INVESTMENT TRUST",
                "INVESTMENT COMPANY",
                "PENSION FUND",
                "INSURANCE BOND",
                "LISTED EQUITY",
                "PREFERENCE SHARE",
                "ZERO DIVIDEND PREF",
                "GILT (CONVENTIONAL)",
                "GILT (INDEX LINKED)",
                "AIM",
                "VCT",
                "OFFSHORE FUND",
                "ETP"
            };
        using (var dealingContext = new dbDealingContainer())
        {
            return (from fundprice in dealingContext.FundPrices
                    where (fundprice.FUND_STATUS == "ACTIVE" || fundprice.FUND_STATUS == "SUSPENDED") &&
                          (fundprice.INVNAME != null || fundprice.INVNAME != "") &&
                          !fundprice.INVNAME.StartsWith("IFSL Bestinvest") &&
                        //  fundprice.WaterlooTradable == true &&
                           fundprice.BID_MID_PRICE > 0 && typeList.Contains(fundprice.FUND_TYPE)
                          && ((sedols.Length > 0 && sedols.Contains(fundprice.SEDOL_NUMBER)) 
                          ||sedols.Contains(fundprice.SEDOL_NUMBER_ACC)) || sedols.Length == 0
                    select new TBI.JV.Business.Objects.Asset
                    {
                        AssetName = fundprice.INVNAME,
                        AssetId = fundprice.Id,
                        AssetType = fundprice.FUND_TYPE,
                        Epic = fundprice.INVESTMENT_CODENAME,
                        StarRating = fundprice.STARLEN,
                        Sedol = fundprice.SEDOL_NUMBER,
                        SedolAcc = fundprice.SEDOL_NUMBER_ACC
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The error is thrown at the following line of code sedols.Length > 0 and also sedols.Length == 0. How do I resolve this. My method should be able to take an empty string array as input and return all records.

Comment: You need to be performing those operations in code, not in your query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Define two variables above the query and than use them instead in the query:

```
var isGreaterThanZero = sedols.Length > 0;
var isEmpty = sedols.Length == 0;
```

Answer (score 6):

**The `Any()` extension method is supported by LINQ to Entities.**

Using `exampleArray.Any()` and `!exampleArray.Any()` means you don't have to declare local variables and fortunately it's a nice, succinct syntax.